# ActiveMQ Проверка дубликатов (Wildfly, Java EE)

Tags: jms, activemq

В проекте реализован JMS при помощи ActiveMQ.

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class Producer {

public void produceMessage(List<String> entityIds) {
    try {
        InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) initialContext.lookup("java:/JmsXA");
        Destination destination = (Destination) initialContext.lookup("jms/queue/cachedAttrs");

        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
        producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);

        entityIds.forEach(entityId -> {                 
                    TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(entityId);
                    message.setStringProperty("_AMQ_DUPL_ID", entityId);
                    producer.send(message);                     
            }
        );

        connection.close();
        session.close();
        initialContext.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("..." + e.getMessage());
    }
}
}

@MessageDriven(
name = "Consumer",
activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "jms/queue/cachedAttrs"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "useDLQ", propertyValue = "false")
}
)
public class Consumer implements MessageListener {  

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    TextMessage id = (TextMessage) message;
}
}
```

Producer.produceMessage() может вызываться из разных мест системы и причем в одно и тоже время.
Есть потребность исключать дублирующиеся ID, чтобы для них Consumer не вызывался. Допустим из одного места вызвали Producer и передали в списке ID ("1"), и из другого места вызвали и тоже передали ("1"), а первый еще не выполнился в очереди.

Согласно документации

> https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/1.0.0/duplicate-detection.html

делаю так:

```
message.setStringProperty("_AMQ_DUPL_ID", entityId);
```

Вызываю Producer:

```
producer.produceMessage(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "1", "3", "2"));
```

На выходе получаю:

```
Caused by: ActiveMQDuplicateIdException[errorType=DUPLICATE_ID_REJECTED message=Duplicate message detected - message will not be routed. Message information:ServerMessage[messageID=266288062339,durable=true,userID=0c03aadc-c07a-11e8-9fb7-775c9c2bdfeb,priority=4, bodySize=225, timestamp=Tue Sep 25 11:18:25 GMT+07:00 2018,expiration=0, durable=true, address=jms.queue.deviceCachedAttrs,properties=TypedProperties[__AMQ_CID=f627a880-c079-11e8-9fb7-775c9c2bdfeb,_AMQ_DUPL_ID=1]]@1895765804]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:406)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:304)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ActiveMQSessionContext.xaPrepare(ActiveMQSessionContext.java:457)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionImpl.prepare(ClientSessionImpl.java:1241)
```

Подскажите где ошибся?

Answer (score 0):

Никакой ошибки нет: требовалось обнаружение дубликатов - оно работает. Текст ошибки достаточно ясно сообщает о обнаружении дубликата. Не смущайтесь тем фактом, что ситуация обрабатывается путём выброса исключения - довольно логичное поведение (как ещё MQ может сообщить о проблеме?). В вызывающем коде можно добавить `catch` блок для отлова исключения `ActiveMQDuplicateIdException` и в нём делать обработку, соответствующую требованиям вашей бизнес-логики, например, просто игнорировать данное исключение.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я ожидал немного другого, но видимо не правильно понял идею.

Comment: Возник вопрос. А где собственно в исходном коде добавить отлов исключения ActiveMQDuplicateIdException? Судя по трейсу падение происходит где-то в глубинах ActiveMQ классов и происходит асинхронно.Ни один из моих catch не отлавливает это исключение

Comment: Получается, что дубликаты просто игнорируются, причём ActiveMQ не даёт возможности как-то дополнительно с этим работать в вызывающем коде. В принципе, задача решена - дубликаты не отправляются. Тот факт, что в лог выводятся ошибки - помогает знать, что дубликаты действительно существуют. Если вывод в лог не нужен - настройте журнализацию в сервере приложений для пропуска этого типа ошибок.